# Height of an irregular tetrahedron with an equilateral base and lateral faces making angles $60^\circ$, $60^\circ$, $80^\circ$ with that base

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d, solid-geometry

> An irregular tetrahedron has a base that is an equilateral triangle of side length $10$.  The lateral faces make angles of $60^\circ, 60^\circ$ and $80^\circ$ with the base.  Find the height of the tetrahedron.

So, one way I thought I could solve this problem is using coordinate geometry, specifically attaching a reference frame to the base, and writing the equations of the three planes that represent the three lateral faces, and then solving the linear system for the apex coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a tetrahedron with base $ABC$ and apex $D$, let

- $E$ be the orthogonal projection of $D$ onto the plane holding $ABC$.
- $h = |DE|$ will be the height of tetrahedron.
- $\theta_A / \theta_B / \theta_C$ be the angle between faces $DBC$ / $DCA$ / $DAB$ and base $ABC$.
- $\ell_A / \ell_B / \ell_C$ be the distance of $E$ to edges $BC$ / $CA$ / $AB$.

As long as all $\theta_A, \theta_B, \theta_C < 90^\circ$, $E$ lies inside $ABC$.
Furthermore, we have

- $\ell_A = h \cot\theta_A$, $\ell_B = h \cot \theta_B$ and $\ell_C = h\cot\theta_C$
- $|BC|\ell_A + |CA|\ell_B + |BC|\ell_C = 2\verb/Area/(ABC)$

For the tetrahedron at hand, we have $|AB| = |BC| = |CA| = 10$ and $\verb/Area/(ABC
) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}(10)^2$.
This leads to

$$\ell_A + \ell_B + \ell_C = 5\sqrt{3}$$

and as a result,
$$\begin{align}
h = \frac{\ell_A + \ell_B + \ell_C}{\cot\theta_A + \cot\theta_B + \cot\theta_C}
&= \frac{5\sqrt{3}}{2\cot(60^\circ) + \cot(80^\circ)} = \frac{15}{2 + \sqrt{3}\cot(80^\circ)}\\
&\sim 6.506442514261543\end{align}$$

Comment: Finally, I have obtained a satisfying answer in a way which is in fact very similar to yours... by invoking barycentric coordinates (with the good formulas this time)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $ABC$ denote the equilateral triangle where the two dihedral angles with values 60° taken along $AB$ and $AC$. Let $H$ be the midpoint of $BC$
and $D$ be the apex of the tetrahedron. Vertical plane $HAD$ is clearly a plane of symmetry of this tetrahedron.

Let $F$ be the foot of the altitude dropped from $D$ onto the horizontal plane; $F$ belongs clearly to line $AH$. We have to find $f:=\text{length}(DF)$.

Let $d:=\text{length}(FH)$.

First, we have:

$$\frac{d}{h}=c \ \ \text{where} \ \ c:=\cot(80°)\approx 0.1763269 \tag{1}$$

It is known (see for example page 3 of [this](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ekmcrane/Projects/Other/nDCotanFormula.pdf) document) that the **barycentric coordinates** of $F$ with respect to base triangle $ABC$ are proportional to the products of the different sidelengths of the base triangle by the cotangent of their associated dihedral angles:

$$(\text{length(AB)} \cot(60°), \ \ \ \text{length(AC)} \cot(60°),  \ \ \  \text{length(BC)} \cot(80°)),$$

themselves proportional to:

$$(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},c) \tag{2}$$

The "true" barycentrical coordinates being obtained by dividing expressions (2) by their sum: $c+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Using the classical areal interpretation of these "true" barycentric coordinates
and taking into account the fact that the area of triangle $ABC$ is $25 \sqrt{3}$, one can identify 2 different ways to express the ratio $\frac{area(HBC)}{area(ABC)}$, i.e.,

$$\frac{\tfrac12 d \times 10}{25 \sqrt{3}}=\frac{c}{c+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}}\tag{3}$$

From (3), one deduces

$$d=\dfrac{5 \sqrt{3}c}{c+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}}$$

Then, from (1), we get the value of

$$h=\frac{d}{c} \approx 6.5064425...$$

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a good idea. First write down the equations of the three sides of the triangle, then find the equations of the straight line for each side such as:

1. The line is perpendical to the side
2. The lines intercepts the side
3. The line has an angle of $\pi/3$ with the side (use trigonometry)

Then you will find the plane with the normal vector $\vec{n}$ (with $\vec{n} = \vec{d}_{line} \times \vec{d}_{side}$) intercepting the only point belonging to both side and line, and finally calculate the interception of the three planes. The final steps should not be a problem (you may use Pythagore or some geometry formula's).
Sorry for my poor English, I hope it will help.

Comment: I just upvoted the non courteous downvoting for somebody who has taken time to give a kind of answer. But I think that here, the OP looks to be aware of ways to solve the issue using coordinate geometry.